# How to fix 'MongoDart Error: Db is in the wrong state: State.OPENING' in Flutter?

Tags: mongodb, flutter

I'm making an app in Flutter that should connect to a MongoDB on a remote server for some functionality (login for example). The problem is that it doesn't matter which server I try to connect to (my computer's or my Google Cloud); I get the same error `"Unhandled Exception: MongoDart Error: Db is in the wrong state: State.OPENING"`. In the catch-handler I also get this error: `"failed SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = 10.0.2.2, port = 54167"`. How can I fix that?

I use the plugin from https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mongo_dart and try to make my function as easy as possible just to see if I can interact with the server in any way. I have changed the config so the servers allow for remote connection.

```
openDB() async {
    //mongo.Db db = new mongo.Db("mongodb://URLtoServer:27017/mongotest");
    mongo.Db db = new mongo.Db("mongodb://10.0.2.2:27017/mongotest"); //toHostComputer
    try {
      await db.open();
    } catch (e) {
      print('failed ${e.toString()}');
    }
    var loginColl = db.collection('LogIn');
    var res = await loginColl.findOne();
    print('$res');
    await db.close();
  }
```

I expected the output to be an example from my collection 'LogIn', but what I instead get is the errors listed above. Therefore I guess that the error must be on the Android Studio Side rather than the server. Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: I think that your mongodb server might not be correctly configured. Try to initialize it with `mongod --bind_ip_all`.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout occurs because the client is unable to connect or receive a response from the server. You need to check if the server has been configured properly. The other error `"Db is in the wrong state"` also indicates that the client is unable to connect to the db. Try [launching a local instance](https://github.com/mongo-dart/mongo_dart/issues/193#issuecomment-683460877) of mongo db first to test if the client has no issues connecting with a server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
db = await Db.create(
    "<Your Connection String>");
await db.open();
```